# cmake acting differently when compiling in different directories

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, c++14, emscripten

my file structure looks like this:

```
gameFolder 
|-cmake-build-debug
|-CMakeLists.txt **for clion build**
|-src
  |-example.cpp
  |-example.h
|-emscripten **web build**
  |-build
  |-CMakeLists.txt
```

the issue here is when I run **cmake ..** in the build folder under emscripten cmake is unable to find the boost library, however when I run **cmake .** in the emscripten folder directly it builds my projects.

I just want to know what's going on here? Is there some secret weird compiler stuff going on? why do I have to run cmake within the same folder as the text file?

**EDIT**:
Here is my enscripten/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(FernQuest)

message(STATUS "running cmake...")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/out)

include_directories(.)


message(STATUS "finding boost!")
find_package(Boost 1.74.0 REQUIRED serialization system filesystem COMPONENTS serialization system filesystem)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "found boost!")
endif()

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif()

message(STATUS "setting sources")
SET(FQ_SRCS
    ../src/FernQuest.cpp
    ../src/Item.cpp
    ../src/Item.h
    ../src/Player.cpp
    ../src/Player.h
    ../src/Game.cpp
    ../src/Game.h
    ../src/QuestLog.cpp
    ../src/QuestLog.h)


SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER emcc)
SET(CMAKE_CPP_COMPILER em++)


add_executable(FernQuest.html ${FQ_SRCS})


if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "found boost!")
    target_link_libraries(FernQuest.html)
    target_link_libraries(FernQuest.html ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

and the error I get when I run it as described

```
build % cmake ..
-- running cmake...
-- finding boost!
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.19.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR serialization system
  filesystem serialization system filesystem) (Required is at least version
  "1.74.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.19.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:582 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.19.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2193 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter what directory you run `cmake` from, unless there's a bug in your `CMakeLists.txt`.  Please edit your post to include the contents of `emscripten/CMakeLists.txt` as well as the full error text.

Comment: For some reason the place where cmake seems to look for boost seem to depend on the build dir for some reason!? Not sure why though. Too little info available.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I updated the post, and its not too much of an issue since I can just run **cmake .** It just messes up my whole build flow

Comment: where is boost installed and how does cmake locate it?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I just did a full reinstall of everything straight from git (boost and emscripten) boost was installed in the /usr/local/include folder and I pointed cmake to it, and it found it. But emscripten is having issues which I submitted in a new post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I stumbled around a bit and found a solution to this:

```
include_directories("path-to-emscripten")
```

for me it was installed using brew so I just entered this at the top and it did the trick

```
include_directory("/usr/local/Cellar")
```